# Audience Targeting not working in SP2010

Tags: 2010, web-part, content-editor-web-part, audience-targeting

We have 3 content editor webparts on Wiki Page.

All the 3 webparts are added using SharePoint Designer. All the webparts have target audience.

We are facing an issues when we deploy the wsp: All 3 content editor webparts are getting visible (target audience isn't working).

What could be the potential problem for audience tageting not working ? But in our stage environment i tried IIS reset , redeploying webparts it worked . But in production i am still having issues .

Comment: Is it working before?

Comment: Hi Waqas , IIS reset works sometimes in stage . But issues pops up after some days .

Comment: the reason i am asking this, in 2010 farmw e had the same issue when target Audience stop working and we figured out that UPA pool stuck ...after recycleing the app pool for UPA service everything works.

Comment: https://lixuan0125.wordpress.com/2012/06/18/audience-targeting-sharepoint-2010/

Comment: i will try to replicate the issue in my stage box and try to capture logs . But thanks i will check for UP service . Also , I recycled the app pool for web app and then tried the iss reset .

Comment: on UPA admin page, is their any error in target audience? stuck on compiling or complied with error?

Comment: If the issue is same as we had then nothing with WebAPp's pool...it is with UPA pool....so on the server where you configured the sync service please reset IIS Over their and see if it fix the issue

Comment: Thats true . What you mean by UPA admin page , error in target audience ?

Comment: central admin> application management > manager services Application > click on UPA> on this page your will see manage audience

Answer (score 0):

If they are audiences and not AD groups or Sharepoint groups, then it is probably an underlying GUID mismatch and it can't be resolved. While named the same, they have unique GUIDs under the hood on the Devs machine and the QA/Prod environment. This is most likely where the problem is.

At a previous employer, they had news which was heavily reliant on audiences. It became problematic and they decided (before I got there) to go into the DB and manually update the audiences so things would work across all environments.